# Strange value for the CN attributes of some groups in Active Directory using CSVDE

Tags: active-directory, csvde

I used CSVDE to export every groups of my Active Directory in a CSV file.
I am looking for the CN attribute ([common-Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675449%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

In my result, i have some CN that have a strange format. (and also longer than the maximum lenght - 64 bytes)

The stranges CN look like:

`X'517565416770705f40726f63c3b964757265725f2d5f61646d696e697374726174696f65f6a4c'`

I can't find out what are those groups and why i get these values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is an [Hexadecimal value that can be converted to string.](http://www.string-functions.com/hex-string.aspx)

The reason why [CSVDE](http://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/cc771621%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) give me an hexadecimal value is that **the initial value contains an accent.**